# Algorithm X to Solve the Exact Cover: Fat Matrices

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra, sudoku

As I was reading about Knuth's Algorithm X to solve the exact cover problem, I thought of an edge case that I wanted some clarification on.

Here are my assumptions:

1. Given a matrix A, Algorithm X's "goal is to select a subset of the rows so that the digit 1 appears in each column **exactly once**."
2. If the matrix is empty, the algorithm terminates successfully and the solution is then the subset of rows logged in the partial solution up to that point.
3. If there is a column of 0's, the algorithm terminates unsuccessfully.

For reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm_X

Consider the matrix A:
[[1 1 0]
 [0 1 1]]

Steps I took:

Given Matrix A:

```
1. Choose a column, c, with the least number of 1's. I choose: column 1

2. Choose a row, r, that contains to a 1 in column c. I choose: row 1

3. Add r to the partial solution.

4. For each column j such that A(r, j) = 1:

       For each row i such that A(i, j) = 1:

           delete row i

       delete column j

5. Matrix A is empty. Algorithm terminates successfully and solution is allegedly: {row 1}.
```

However, this is clearly not the case as row 1 only consists of [1 1 0] and clearly does not cover the 3rd column.

I would assume that the algorithm should at some point reduce the matrix to the point where there is only a single 0 and terminate unsuccessfully.

Could someone please explain this?

Comment: did you consider using max flow? e.g. for each column have a node which has and edge of capacity 1 going to the sink.

Comment: I didn't consider max flow because I was just looking at this algorithm in particular. To be more specific I want to apply this algorithm to sudokus and this method is one of the better known/best solution. Thanks for suggesting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion here is simply in the use of the term *empty matrix*. If you read Knuth's original paper (linked on the Wikipedia article you cited), you can see that he was treating the rows and columns as doubly-linked lists. When he says that the matrix is empty, he doesn't mean that it has no entries, he means that all the row and column objects have been deleted.

To clarify, I'll label the rows with lower case letters and the columns with upper case letters, as follows:

```
   | A | B | C
---------------
 a | 1 | 1 | 0
---------------
 b | 0 | 1 | 1
```

The algorithm states that you choose a column deterministically (using any rule you wish), and he suggests choosing a column with the fewest number of 1's. So, we'll proceed as you suggest and choose column *A*. The only row with a 1 in column *A* is row *a*, so we choose row *a* and add it to the possible solution { *a* }. Now, row *a* has 1s in columns *A* and *B*, so we must delete those columns, and any rows containing 1s in those columns, that is, rows *a* and *b*, just as you did. The resulting matrix has a single column *C* and no rows:

```
   | C
-------
```

This is not an empty matrix (it has a column remaining). However, column *C* has no 1s in it, so we terminate unsuccessfully, as the algorithm indicates.

This may seem odd, but it is a very important case if we intend to use an incidence matrix for the [Exact Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover), because columns represent elements of the set X that we wish to cover and rows represents subsets of X. So a matrix with some columns and no rows represents the exact covering problem where the collection of subsets to choose from is empty (but there are still points to cover).

If this description causes problems for your implementation, there is a simple workaround: just include the empty set in every problem. The empty set (containing no points of X) is represented by a row of all zeros. It is never selected by your algorithm as part of a solution, never collides with any other selected rows, but always ensures that the matrix is nonempty (there is at least one row) until all the columns have been deleted, which is really all you care about since you need to make sure that each column is covered by some row.

Comment: After reading over Knuth's implementation of dancing links, it makes much more sense. By just using the matrix directly, I didn't account for having a header row of columns. This means in order for the matrix to be empty, the header row must also be empty. Does this sound correct?

Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: Yeah, you could do it either way: a header row of columns that you treat specially, or you just insert a row of all zeros somewhere in the matrix.